# How to use multiple variables directly with CDOSYS parameters in Classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic, cdo.message, cdonts

I am writing email sending code in Classic ASP using CDOSYS, but what i found when i try to write variables concatenation with CDOSYS parameters its gives me error.

I could not write code in following way-

```
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "admin@" & website
```

it givees me following error while execution - CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'

while following code works fine as its having single variable-

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = websiteemail
```

Note:- Reason to use in that way because my client having many sites and previously we used CDONTS and ASPEMAILS and it used to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I created:

```
function email(s_from,s_reply_to,s_recipients,s_bcc,s_subject,s_msg,s_type,s_msg_error_add,s_remote_host)

    if (s_msg_error_add<>"") then s_msg_error_add = "<hr>" & vbCrLf & s_msg_error_add
    if (s_remote_host="default") then s_remote_host = application("s_mail_server")
        if (s_remote_host="") then s_remote_host = "localhost"
    s_remote_host=lcase(s_remote_host)

    's_recipients looks like "Scott <scott@domain.net>; Sue <andy@domain.net>" etc

    s_from = replace(s_from,","," ",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"[","<",1,-1,1)
    s_from = replace(s_from,"]",">",1,-1,1)

    if (s_reply_to<>"") then
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,","," ",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"[","<",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"]",">",1,-1,1)
    end if

    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,",",";",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"[","<",1,-1,1)
    s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"]",">",1,-1,1)

    if (s_bcc<>"") then 
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,","," ",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"[","<",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"]",">",1,-1,1)
    end if

    err.clear

    Dim MailerConfig
    Dim Mailer
    Dim strRet
    dim sch

    strRet = ""
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

    Set MailerConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set Mailer = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With MailerConfig.Fields
        '.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 'send using port - if err then this is really "SendUsingMethod"
        '.Item(sch & "sendusingmethod") = 2 'send using port - if err then this is really "SendUsingMethod"
        .Item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 900
        '.Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'use basic (clear-text) authentication
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = s_remote_host
        '.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
        '.Item(sch & "sendusername") = SMAUTHUSER
        '.Item(sch & "sendpassword") = SMAUTHPASS
        .Update
    End With
    Mailer.Configuration = MailerConfig

    'Mailer.Fields(cdoImportance) = 1
    'Mailer.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = 1
    'Mailer.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Mailer") = ""
    'Mailer.Fields.Update

    '-- Set the Mail Properties

    'on error resume next

    Mailer.From = s_from
    Mailer.To = s_recipients
    if (s_reply_to<>"" and s_reply_to<>"na") then Mailer.ReplyTo = s_reply_to

    b_redirect=false

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 72, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_bcc<>"" AND s_bcc<>"na" AND s_bcc<>"n/a") then Mailer.BCC = s_bcc

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 79, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Mailer.Subject = s_subject

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 86, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_type="html") then
        Mailer.AutoGenerateTextBody = True
        s_msg = replace(s_msg,vbCrLf,"<br>",1,-1,1)
    else
        Mailer.AutoGenerateTextBody = False         
    end if

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 103, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Mailer.MimeFormatted = False

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 110, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    if (s_type = "text") then
        Mailer.TextBody = fn_dirty(s_msg)
    else
        's_msg_html = replace(s_msg,vbCrLf,"<br>",1,-1,1)
        s_msg_html = s_msg
        Mailer.HTMLBody = fn_dirty(s_msg_html)
    end if

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        session("msg") = "Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp line 123, Error: " & err.number & "<br>" & err.description
        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    '-- Fire off the email message

    Mailer.Send

    if (err.number<>0 and err.number<>13) then
        Select Case err.Number
            Case -2147220973
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Not Found" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " &  err.Description
            Case -2147220975
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Authentication Failed" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
            Case Else
                strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
        End Select

        msg = "<br>Error in i_fn_email_cdo.asp: " & strRet & "<br><br>"

            msg = msg & "remote host = " & s_remote_host & "<br>"
        s_from = replace(s_from,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_from = replace(s_from,">","]",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,"<","]",1,-1,1)
        s_reply_to = replace(s_reply_to,">","[",1,-1,1)
        s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_recipients = replace(s_recipients,">","]",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,"<","[",1,-1,1)
        s_bcc = replace(s_bcc,">","]",1,-1,1)

        msg = msg & "from = " & s_from & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "to = " & s_recipients & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "subject = " & s_subject & "<br>"
        msg = msg & "recipients = " & s_recipients & "<br><br>"

        if (s_type = "text") then
            msg = msg & s_msg
        else
            msg = msg & s_msg_html
        end if
        msg = msg & "<br>"      
        msg = msg & s_msg_error_add
        session("msg") = msg
        Set Mailer = Nothing
        set MailerConfig = nothing

        if (b_redirect) then response.redirect ("error_report.asp?send_mail=yes")
    end if

    Set Mailer = Nothing
    set MailerConfig = nothing

    email = true

end function
```